# Construct a batch without relying on a single instance of the WriteBatch class

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to build a set of batch actions using functions that don't rely on a single instance of WriteBatch. Right now, I have to pass in an instance of the WriteBatch class to the functions which can then call the `.set()` or `.update()` or `.delete()` functions on the batch.

Take my code example:

```
export class BatchHelperService {

  constructor(private afStore: AngularFirestore) { }

  executeBatchActions(batchActions: BaseBatchAction[]): Observable<void> {
    const batch = this.afStore.firestore.batch();
    batchActions.forEach(action => action.attachActionToBatch(batch));
    return from(batch.commit());
  }
}
```

I have a function here that takes an array of a base class `BaseBatchAction`. I have three derived classes representing the three batch action types (set, update, delete). They all implement the `attachActionToBatch()` function, but it relies on passing in an already created `WriteBatch` object.

I want to remove this dependency as it violates the clean code principal for monadic functions (avoid using output arguments). Is this possible with the SDK?

Comment: Whilst you could make `action.attachActionToBatch()` take one or none arguments, and create the batch as needed, where is it going to get the `firestore` instance to create the batch in the first place and how are you going to chain multiple operations in the batch? I believe what you have now to be the most understandable code you can use. As long as your abstracted API is understandable and follows the monadic paradigm, I don't see why the code to achieve it must also be monadic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use WriteBatch.  There is no alternative to writing a Firestore batch that avoids this construct.  It will always be there somewhere.

What you can do instead, if you're trying to separate concerns, is create your own batch abstraction/encapsulation (perhaps a wrapper object) that doesn't reveal any of the Firestore APIs externally, yet uses them internally.  You can pass around this wrapper objects and have your code deal with in in a way you find agreeable.  It looks like you've started that a bit with BaseBatchAction, but I think you'll need to make a bigger abstraction the abstacts the entire batch, not just an individual change.